# Install dotnet without admin rights on windows 7

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I need to install dotnet (.Net 6+) on user machines without administrator privileges. Using instruction from [microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net60) I extract dotnet files to folder and set DOTNET_ROOT and PATH environmental variables for user. It works perfectly on machines with Windows 10, but on machines with windows 7 my programs don't work and 'dotnet' command not recognised. If I install dotnet with standard installer with administrator rights it works. What am I missing?